# Breaking change on getting status update history

Tags: facebook-fql, status

I have noticed that querying the status table for historical data lead to different results recently, without any notification or warning by Facebook.

Before, we could get any status updates past june 2009.
Now we can only query status from the last 100 status updates.

Can anyone confirm this ?

Thanks !

Comment: actually the Facebook bug tracker was down when I wrote this, here is the corresponding bug report : 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/155458081230560?browse=search_4f22e62b44d141d45304788

Comment: The bug is still on,  a new bug report has been created :
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/189017134535717

Answer (score 0):

Facebook apparently is now limiting the amount of information stored for each object.  They recently announced 50 for one of the lists (only via a bug report) and I presume they're heading to try to decrease their costs of warehousing so much data for the public free API.